# Push datepicker date to url in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I wonder how can I update my url (i.e. `www.example.com/main?date=2013-03-03`) where part `?date=2013-03-03` is dynamically changed once the date in the datepicker is updated.

Datepicker 's date format is `yyyy-MM-dd`

My datepicker looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-change="changeDay()"
  datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="selectedDay" is-open="false"
  ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```

Angularjs controller is this:

```
$scope.selectedDay = new Date();
  $scope.changeDay = function() {
  getData(dateToString($scope.selectedDay));
};
```

I have tried with $routeParams and $location.search but I am not quite sure how to use it.